# aggregating an object with __call() function

Tags: php

so i wanted to make and object (for example person) which consists of some info like id,name and **address** but because person isn't the only object that needs this parameter i made another class for it like this the problem being i get nothing in return just a blank page no error or anything:

```
class address
{
    public $city;
    public $street;
    public $alley;
public function setcity($city)
{
    $this->city=$city;
}
public function getcity()
{
    return $this->city;
}
public function setstreet($street)
{
    $this->street=$street;
}
public function getstreet()
{
    return $this->street;
}
public function setalley($alley)
{
    $this->alley=$alley;
}
public function getalley()
{
    return $this->alley;
}}
```

person.php :

```
require_once "address.php";

class person 
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $st_id;
    public $address;

    public  function  __construct()
    {
       $this->address=new address();
    }
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
       if(method_exists($this->address,$name))
       {
return call_user_func_array(array($this->address,$name),$arguments);
       }
    }
/* public function printm()
    {
        print $this->name. " ".$this->address->city. " ".$this->address->street. " ".$this->address->alley;
    }*/}
```

Comment: And what? Did you create object of class `person`? Or just defined two classes and wait for something?

Comment: yes of course i did problem being it's just returns empty so i thought it was my classes problem

Comment: Why is your `person` extending `address` ___and___ instantiating  a new `address` as a property of `person`?

Comment: hmm ok let me edit this

Comment: If `person` extends `address`, then all the methods inherited from `address` are public, so `__call()` will never be invoked for them, they'll be called directly

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/CWPOH)

Comment: i rather use __call() so how should i change this?

Comment: Look at the demo I just posted a link to.... without extending `person`, the call is populating `$this->address` because `__call()` is being invoked; otherwise, if you simply "extend" address, then the address methods are called directly, populating the "extended" `city` etc properties, without touching the `address` object property that your constructor has instantiated

Comment: so it should return the name of the city right? in the demo i mean

Comment: It does return the name of the city ([modified demo](https://3v4l.org/CWPOH))

Comment: never mind got it

Comment: thank you mark i appreciate it